# Laravel Eloquent JOIN WHERE id is null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I cant work out how to do the equivalent of a join statement in eloquent.

Basically from the below code I want a query like the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Vehicle v
JOIN VehicleImage i ON v.id = i.vehicle_id
limit 24
```

This is the query I am currently using:

```
$cars = Vehicle::with(['images' => function($q){
    $q->orderBy('order');
}])->take(24)->get();
```

currently its bringing back all vehicles regardless of whether they have an image or not- so a left join i guess. I dont want this, I only want rows which have 1 or more image. Is this possible?

```
  class Vehicle extends Eloquent
    {

        public function images()
        {

            return $this->hasMany('App\Domain\Vehicles\VehicleImage');

        }
    }

    class VehicleImage extends Eloquent {

        public function vehicle()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Domain\Vehicles\Vehicle');
        }

    }
```

Comment: It doen't join for `with`. It's eager loadin and it uses 2 queries. The second is `IN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doen't join for `with`. It's eager loading and it uses 2 queries. The second is `IN`.

So if you wan't to use JOIN equivalent, use Query Builder.

`Vehicle::leftJoin('...')->get();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries

Also, if you want to monitor your queries, install this package:

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that what I'm trying to do is not achievable using eloquent models alone? Meaning that I can use one model (Vehicles) with a join, but not both?

Comment: Why?
It only means that you can use ORM-way or Query Builder Way. But ORM won't use JOINs. Also you can mix and match them in any way because they are compatible.

Comment: I think it should be inner join do the answer is: `Vehicle::join('...')->get();

`